# method and dataset for credit card fraud detection

Tags: python, feature-engineering, anomaly-detection

I am trying to create a machine learning model to detect credit card fraud (In our definition, fraud means chargeback). I am kinda stuck now with the dataset that I have. I don't have information on the item, quantity, or shipping address. I have information on the credit card, amount to charge, ip address since we are a payment gateway.

Is it possible to do fraud detection using the this kind of dataset? The features I created out of existing dataset can't detect the chargeback very well.

I have tried:

- velocity check analysis. ie. checking numbers of transaction past x hours, past x days. Checking number of unique Card used per IP or unique IP used per card.
- anomaly detection. ie. checking out what transaction amount is considered normal for a merchant or how many transactions per day is considered normal.
- oversampling/undersampling. We have highly imbalanced dataset and that's why I am doing oversampling.

Is there any other method I can try or is it even possible to do proper fraud detection with my current dataset?

Comment: Just to clear things up, is the only information you have the credit card id, the transaction amount and the ip adress? Or do you have any additional information as well?

Comment: Do you have information on the time? Weekday or hour? Or information about on where is the IP located?

Comment: @georg_un I have additional information such as which merchant is making the transaction (since we are payment gateway, we have multiple merchants doing using our services), charge time as well. I have info on ECI, whether the credit card is authorized and authenticated or not but turns out this is not good indicator of chargeback.

Comment: @JuanEstebandelaCalle yes I have information on charge time and I can get weekday and hour from there. From the IP address,I can look up where it is located. There are few APIs that do this. I normally try to match the card's origin country vs IP's country but that's not always a good indicator of chargebacks.